# PagingSample using AndroidX

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions

I tried to refactor PagingSample(Google's android-architecture-components) to AndroidX(AndroidStudio 3.3.0-alpha11, kotlin_plugin=1.3.0-rc-57)

Gradle build was done without errors. Debugging gives error:

> app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/../pagingsample/CheeseAdapter.java:33: 
>   error: cannot find symbol private static final androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil.ItemCallback diffCallback = null;
>                                                                               ^symbol:   class T
>                                                                               location: class CheeseAdapter

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

```
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.paging.PagedListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil

class CheeseAdapter : PagedListAdapter<Cheese, CheeseViewHolder>(/*diffCallback)*/
object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Cheese>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Cheese, newItem: Cheese): Boolean =
        oldItem.id == newItem.id

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Cheese, newItem: Cheese): Boolean =
        oldItem == newItem
}) {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CheeseViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindTo(getItem(position))
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CheeseViewHolder =
        CheeseViewHolder(parent)

}
```